# Передача значения из MSSQL в Postgres

Tags: sql-server, bash, postgresql9.5

Имеется база на MSSQL и база на Postgres.
Требуется сделать выборку в MSSQL, при этой выборке получим только одно значение и обновить ячейку в Postgres.
Решение данной задачи вижу через .bat файл. Если есть другие пути решения прошу их перечислить.
Единственная проблема в том, что не могу понять как передать полученное значение из SQLCMD в переменную CMD, что бы далее ее передать в PSQL. (Это вообще возможно? были предложения записывать результат MSSQL в файл, а потом парсить)

Comment: так на [сайте](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-postgresql-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15) производителя есть инструкция, как взаимодействовать MS SQL с другими СУБД.

Comment: Спасибо, о данной возможности не знал.